# PhpActiveRecord: Creating initialize object

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I'm using [php activerecord](http://phpactiverecord.org/). I need initialize a `Order` object and then set related objects as show below

```
$order = new Order();
Order->_plan = Plan::find(1);
```

I get the error `Undefined property: Order->_plan in /var/www/ordenes-web/core/libs/php-activerecord/lib/Model.php on line 428`

My class:

```
class Order extends ActiveRecord\Model{
    static $belongs_to = array( 
        array(
            '_plan',
            'class_name' => 'Plan',
            'foreign_key' => 'plan'
        ),
    );
}
```

The relationship works fine. If I find an `Order` with the finder I get the related object `_plan`:

```
Order::find(1)->_plan // Works!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `class Orden != class Order` - I hope thats a mistake in the question not your code ??

Comment: My mistake. I translated the name of the class and I forgot that line.

Comment: may be just try this: `'_plan' => '',` ?

Comment: @StasGrin I tried as you said `$orden = new Orden(array('_plan' => plan::find(1)));` but I get the same error.

Comment: hm. dont try to set `_plan` at same time u activate it. Just add (or replace) to your "class" my line. It is 4th line in your example. Check it out pls.

Comment: @StasGrin sorry I don't understand  where I should add or replace your line. Could you explain? Thanks!

Comment: @Overflow012 http://pastebin.com/qyY4qSxW

Comment: Thank you again @StasGrin but the error persists.

Comment: :( so.. i don't know now what to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ActiveRecord not support this behavior. You can see [here](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/1/topics/573-set-relationship)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
Order->_plan
```

Really doesn't mean anything. You can find the properties of an object, for instance, your `$order` object.

This line means you are making an object and then finding the `_plan` property. Which is good.

```
 Order::find(1)->_plan // Works!
```

To do this with an object, you should do

```
$order = Order::find(1);
var_dump($order->_plan;) // should work!
```

Now you can change stuff in your _plan (if it is there), like

```
$order->_plan->world = "Hello".
```

Now you should remember that you set the relationship in you objects, so that's is how they are reached. You're not supposed to created objects like this I think.The example you say that works does something like

- find the order with id 1.
- get its plan.

But your example that doesn't work does something else

- find a new order
- assign the plan with id 1 to that order.

The last part doesn't work like that I think, see [this link](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/boards/1/topics/573-set-relationship) that @Overflow012 posted.

Comment: Line `Order->_plan` is wrong. Should be `$order->_plan` as you said but does not work anyway. Thanks!